expo-camera doesn't work when making changes to barcodeTypes
I am using expo camera to scan product codes. My idea is as follows, when I change the allowQR variable (this is a state), the barcodeTypes will be changed. But this only works on IOS, on andoird it doesn't seem to work? Can someone explain the cause? Thanks a lot
<CameraView
  onBarcodeScanned={handleScanCode}
  barcodeScannerSettings={{
    barcodeTypes: allowQR
      ? ["qr"]
      : ["code128", "ean13", "ean8", "upc_a", "upc_e"],
  }}
  style={style}
/>```


I want it to work exactly as it is shown in the code

